# Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub;

Tags: android, install-referrer

I updated the

```
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:X'
```

from `1.1.2` to `2.0`

then started getting this error:

```
Process: com.tomatedigital.lottogram, PID: 13424
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub;
        at com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClientImpl.startConnection(InstallReferrerClientImpl.java:36)
        at com.tomatedigital.lottogram.app.App.saveReferralInfo(App.java:221)
        at com.tomatedigital.lottogram.app.App.onCreate(App.java:102)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

the code was not changed from the last version (that worked fine)

```
final InstallReferrerClient mReferrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build();
        try {
            mReferrerClient.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener() {
                public void onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
                     //do stuff
                }

                @Override
                public void onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
             

        }
    }
```

im testing on emulator with android 10
does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Same problem here, both with emulator and real devices. I think its a Google's bug but not 100% sure.

Comment: Any solution for this? Is it perhaps related to appsflyer?

Comment: Same issue for me, any solution ?

Comment: Today was released the 2.1 version and it fixed my problem... im still not secure if worth update

Comment: try to invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @RafaelLima I got an issue with it, that it couldn't find "CampaignTrackingReceiver". Do you know if this has changed, perhaps? Need some migration steps from 1.1.2 ?